# newline margin doesnt look good

Tags: html, css

I have a href, which comes after a sentence. but according to the words it can in the same line with the sentence or in a new line. but because of the margin-left:5px; it doesn't look good when it is in a newline. how can i make it that if there isn't any other words in the left it would start from the very beginning. http://jsfiddle.net/tVC43/11/

```
<div class="box" style="border:1px solid red;">
   welcome to xxxxxxxxx part.
  <nobr style="margin-left:5px">hi thomas</nobr>
  </div>
  <div class="box" style="left:200px; border:1px solid red;">
   welcome to xxxxxxxxx.
  <nobr style="margin-left:5px">hi thomas</nobr>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `<nobr>`? I don't find that in your example and in your example everything looks good.

The default styling for links should mean that they display correctly in line with text. Unless your links are `display: block` or `display: inline-block` then `margin` will not behave as you expect over multiple lines of text.

See here for more explanation: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-formatting

Answer (score 0):

Jsfiddle example updated. Add some css rules over the `nobr` as shown below.

```
<div class="box" style="border:1px solid red;">
   welcome to xxxxxxxxx part.
  <nobr>hi thomas</nobr>
</div>
<div class="box" style="left:200px; border:1px solid red;">
   welcome to xxxxxxxxx.
  <nobr>hi thomas</nobr>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box{
  width:155px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid; 
  position:absolute;
}

nobr {
    clear: left;
    display: block;
}
```

`float: left` & `display: block;`

Please let me know.

---

Solution #2: - simply remove `style="margin-left:5px"` from the second `nobr`

Comment: edited my answer based on your code update, `nobr` doesn't requires any inline styling. also i would suggest to write in css the border color, not inline css.

Comment: <nobr> actually works for me because i don't want the two words to be separated in newline. also this is not the answer i was looking for because in the first div "hi thomas" goes to a new line, i want my final outputs to be like my jsfiddle outputs expect in the second one i dont want a space before "hi thomas".

Comment: then simply remove `style="margin-left:5px"` from the second `nobr`

Comment: :):) i get the data from the server so it is changeable these two divs are the scenarios that could possibly happen.

Comment: sorry? you confuse me, if it's changeable, why don't you changing it?

Comment: the nobr datas come from the server so it can be in any length, in one condition it will be near a sentence, which i want a 5px space if there is a word in the left. in the other case it will start in a new line but i dont want that 5x space if it is in the newline? which i showed both conditions in the demo.

Comment: on the jsfiddle example the next trick does the result: `nobr { margin-left: 0 !important; }`